# A coin has ever-decreasing probability of landing heads on the nth toss. When can we expect it to land on heads in finite time?

Tags: probability

Let $p(n)$ be some monotonically non-increasing function $0 \leq p(n) \leq 1$. Suppose we toss, for an infinite number of times, a coin whose probability of landing on heads in the $nth$ toss, assuming it hasn't already landed on heads, is $p(n)$. For what asymptotic behavior of $p(n)$ can we expect the coin to land on heads in expected finite time?

To clarify, the probability $p(n)$ is the conditional probability that the coin will land on heads in the $nth$ toss, assuming it hasn't already landed on heads. So we can for example take $p(n)=\frac{1}{2n}$ and even though the harmonic series diverges, the probability is still well-defined.

As an example, if $p(n)=c$ is constant, the coin will land on heads in expected finite time.

Comment: Do you need a necessary condition?

Comment: No, just a good sufficient one.

Comment: There will be many sufficient conditions. Don't know what is good. For example, $\inf p(n)>0$ is one. A weaker one could be $\inf_{n\geq k} p(n)>0$ for some $k$.

Comment: @user295959 Okay. So, for specificity - assume $p(x)$ is a continuous monotonically decreasing function (and we look at its value at points $p(n)$ for every integer $n$), and assume that its limit is 0 as $n$ goes to infinity. I want to bound $p(x)$ by some big-O that will guarantee heads in expected finite time.

Comment: $p(1)=1$ and $p(x)=0$ otherwise. Easy to make it differentiable. For any $n>0$, $p(n)=1$, otherwise $p(x)=0$ works too.

Comment: @user295959 This is not what the question is asking for. I am looking for asymptotic behavior, such as $p(n)$ should be asymptotically bigger than $1/n$. Sorry if you are confused, I don't know if I can make it clearer for you.

Comment: I have already given you an example where $p(n)\rightarrow 0$ but the desired property holds. This is exactly why I asked you whether you are looking for a necessary condition.

Comment: If you can find a necessary condition, then that is great. I am not explicitly looking for one, only for a condition that is very close to a necessary condition asymptotically.

Comment: I have already told you your conjecture is wrong!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34057/discussion-between-michael-and-user295959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the probability that your coin will never land on head is :
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty 1 - p (n)$$
if that infinite product doesn't converge to $0$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln (1 - p (n))$ will converge or equivalently :
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty p (n) $$
converge.

Comment: This, however is not the same as the expected time before getting a head being finite.  If we let $p(n)=1/2$ if $n$ is a power of two and 0 otherwise (I'm ignoring the monotinicity condition for simplicity sake, you can spread the probabilities to taste as long as the probabilities of reaching a power of two is about the same) then $\sum p(n)$ diverges, so we are guaranteed to get a head, but the expected time before a head is achieved is not finite.  This is a thinly disguised St Petersburg paradox.

Comment: the expected time should be
$$\sum_{N=1}^\infty N p(N+1) \prod_{n=1}^N 1-p(n)$$ 
so that we should look at 
$$\sum_{N=1}^\infty N p(N+1) \exp(- \sum_{n=1}^N p(n))$$
i.e. there exists a sequence such that $\sum a_N$ converges and 
$$\ln N + \ln p(N+1) - \sum_{n=1}^N p(n) < \ln a_N$$
???????????

Comment: Something like that should work.  (I'm not the person asking the question, and I am not sure he knows exactly what he wants.)